# Changing axis labels in Kendo React Charts

Tags: charts, kendo-react-ui

I have a react chart using Kendo React Charts and I'm simply trying to change the labels on the x-axis, but I cannot find any references or example code to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code I am working with.... I want to use the xaxisLabels to replace the numeric values shown on the x-axis of the chart.

const [firstSeries, secondSeries] = [
[100, 123, 234, 343, 300, 120], [100, 67, 231, 196, 300, 120],];
const categories = ["Discharge in Rod", "Corona on End Fitting", "Lightning Flashover", "Contamination", "Wetting Discharge Activity", "Ultraviolet Light"];
const xaxisLabels = ["Low", "Medium", "Medium High", "High"];

.......[my current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuY8s.png)

```
<Chart>
    <ChartArea border={{ color: "black" }} />
    <ChartTitle text="" />
    <ChartCategoryAxis>
        <ChartCategoryAxisItem categories={categories}>
            <ChartCategoryAxisTitle text="" />
        </ChartCategoryAxisItem>
    </ChartCategoryAxis>
    <ChartSeries>
        <ChartSeriesItem type="bar" gap={2} spacing={0.25} data={firstSeries} />
        <ChartSeriesItem type="bar" data={secondSeries} />
    </ChartSeries>
</Chart>
```